# How can I change the icon of a unity web app?

Tags: icons, webapps

I installed the Tumblr web app but the icon looks horrible. I was wondering if there is any way to change it to a nicer looking one.
I've tried changing the icon in the .icons folder but it always seems to revert back to the usual horrible one.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! If changing the icon doesn't work you could alternatively create your own launcher, give [this question on creating launchers in Unity](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand/234373#234373) a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alacarte` (Main Menu) can add **webapps icon images** to app menu items (`alacarte` needs to be installed)

In 12.04/12.10 I have been finding webapps menu items in the *Other* category.